# Why cannot I overwrite this CSS with a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wish to have this code:

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function(){ $('#form1').submit(); }, 200);
  document.getElementById( "textdisplay" ).style.color = "yellow";
});
```

overwrite this CSS masterpiece by "Joash" https://codepen.io/joashp/pen/dYXNwj,
so that when I click the button, the text receiving Joash's animation will turn yellow and stay that way until function timeout ends.

It is not working and the animation just continues.

Here is my code:

```js
jQuery('.text').html(function(i, html) {
  var chars = jQuery.trim(html).split("");

  return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
});
jQuery('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('#form1').submit();
  }, 2000);
  document.getElementById("textdisplay").style.color = "yellow";
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #161616;
  color: #bdbdbd;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "segoe ui", roboto, oxygen, ubuntu, cantarell, "fira sans", "droid sans", "helvetica neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#submitbutton {
  width: 35%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  background-color: #e4bb97;
  border: 2px solid #3D3B3C;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  color: #3D3B3C;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  border-radius: 17px;
}

#form1 {
  color: red;
  background-color: green;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen);
#textdisplay,
#textdisplay-hover:hover {
  /*
   * Elements settings
   */
}

#textdisplay span,
#textdisplay-hover:hover span {
  -webkit-animation-name: color-text-flow-keys;
  animation-name: color-text-flow-keys;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 50s;
  animation-duration: 50s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color-text-flow-keys {
  0% {
    color: #d65c97;
  }
  5% {
    color: #5cd666;
  }
  10% {
    color: #a55cd6;
  }
  100% {
    color: #64d65c;
  }
}

@keyframes color-text-flow-keys {
  0% {
    color: #d65c97;
  }
  90% {
    color: #5cd666;
  }
  95% {
    color: #d67e5c;
  }
  100% {
    color: #64d65c;
  }
}

#color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(1),
#color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -19.8s;
  animation-delay: -19.8s;
}

#color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(100),
#color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(100) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

body {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: #fefefe;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.txt {
  display: block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
    <button type="submit" id="submitbutton"></button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id='textdisplay'>
    <span>BlueBox</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.style.Color` Capitalization matters in programming (and there's also no `submitbutton` in the link, please post all relevant code in the question itself in a [MCVE])

Comment: That's the problem.

Comment: Added the code :D

Comment: The text which will ultimately have to use this `color` information is a direct child of `#textdisplay span`. Since it will inherit from its element ancestors, it will use the computed value of this `#textdisplay span` element, which is set in the animation `color-text-flow-keys`. Changing the grand-parent `#textdisplay` will have as little influence as if you did change the `color` of let's say `body`.

Comment: so it can't be done?;-;

Comment: are you sure you inserted the correct code? I've turned it into a snippet so that we can check the result and it doesn't seem to work at all (for me, pressing the button doesn't do a thing and when the focus leaves it, the whole thing disappears)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more minimal example, you can remove all the CSS except `#textdisplay span {` and `@keyframes color-text-flow-keys {`:

```js
jQuery('.text').html(function(i, html) {
  var chars = jQuery.trim(html).split("");

  return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
});
jQuery('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('submitting');
  }, 2000);
  document.getElementById("textdisplay").style.color = "yellow";
});
```

```css
#textdisplay span {
  -webkit-animation-name: color-text-flow-keys;
  animation-name: color-text-flow-keys;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 50s;
  animation-duration: 50s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes color-text-flow-keys {
  0% {
    color: #d65c97;
  }
  90% {
    color: #5cd666;
  }
  95% {
    color: #d67e5c;
  }
  100% {
    color: #64d65c;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
    <button type="submit" id="submitbutton">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id='textdisplay'>
    <span>BlueBox</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks like the infinite animation, with its `color:`, results in the `color` property of the element being ignored. One way to fix it would be to run the animation only when the element has a particular class, and remove the class when the button is clicked:

```js
jQuery('.text').html(function(i, html) {
  var chars = jQuery.trim(html).split("");

  return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
});
jQuery('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('submitting');
  }, 2000);
  document.querySelector('#textdisplay > span').classList.remove('anim');
  document.getElementById("textdisplay").style.color = "yellow";
});
```

```css
#textdisplay span.anim {
  -webkit-animation-name: color-text-flow-keys;
  animation-name: color-text-flow-keys;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 50s;
  animation-duration: 50s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes color-text-flow-keys {
  0% {
    color: #d65c97;
  }
  90% {
    color: #5cd666;
  }
  95% {
    color: #d67e5c;
  }
  100% {
    color: #64d65c;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
    <button type="submit" id="submitbutton">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id='textdisplay'>
    <span class="anim">BlueBox</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm going to name my firstborn child "CertainPerformance", thank you!